# Python + selenium + Geckodriver

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется парсер , который должен выполнять определенные функции на сайте. Используется селениум с драйвером Firefox. На сайте необходимо сначала пройти авторизацию с капчей. Можно ли сохранить пароли в geckodriver и каким образом это делается, чтобы каждый запускаемый экземпляр при переходе на сайт автоматически логинился, а не запускался с настройками по умолчанию? (если это можно сделать например в chromedriver-e, то буду признателен за пример)

Comment: Я конечно не знаю как авторизация происходит, но возможно отправка cookie поможет вам. Но капчу придется все равно вводить

Comment: driver.manage().getCookies(); Думаю дальше разберетесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать какой-то определённый профиль Хрома или Файрфокса и логиниться сразу в него. Идея в том чтобы использовать "живой" профиль в котором каждый раз не запрашивают капчу.

Не уверен будет ли работать  такой метод в firefox, но можно попробовать:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(path_to_ff_exe)
profile = FirefoxProfile(path_to_ff_profile)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=path_to_geckodriver)
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

В Chrome можно попробовать следующее:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format(path_to_your_chrome_profile)) 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_exe, chrome_options=options)
```